# Publishing an array from the server to the client

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an array in if Meteor.isServer that pushes userIds to the array when they login and removes said userid on logout. In order to do this I am using the Profile-Online package (https://github.com/erundook/meteor-profile-online). I want to make unique templates depending on the amount of users being 0, 1 or 2 users connected I need to make the array in the server side available to the client without it I can't make templates based on the amount of users. I tried to publish the array in the server and subscribe in client. I have an idea I'm doing something totally and completely wrong. My main objective is to make the array(`playerArray`) accessible from the client.

JS file:

```
Games = new Meteor.Collection("games")
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    //testing if subscribe returns IDs from the array which it doesn't
    Meteor.subscribe("ingame",function(test){console.log(test)})
}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  playerArray = []
  Meteor._onLogin  = function (userId){
    if(!_.contains(playerArray, userId)){
      playerArray.push(userId)
    }
    console.log(playerArray)
  }
   Meteor._onLogout  = function (userId){
    playerArray = _.without(playerArray, userId);
    console.log(playerArray);
   }
   Meteor.publish("ingame",function(){
    return playerArray
   })
}
```

Comment: Why not use a collection?

Comment: Also checkout https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-presence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite the newbie at meteor, but this should work:

1. create a collection `CurrentUsers` into which you insert on `_onLogin` and from which you remove on `_onLogout`,
2. then on the client's side ask `ClientUsers.find({}).count()` and it return the number of logged in users

I suspect that the array approach isn't scalable (won't work for multiple node processes), but this should work OK

Comment: works good, can't figure out how to remove the users on login but I think I'll figure it out thanks!!